# Matching Two Different Paths

Tags: path, pathfinder, line-art

I have two separate paths. I want to match the pink tongue to the black mouth outline as perfectly as possible. Is there a better way to do this without manually moving all the vector points by hand?

[image]
[image]

They need to match up as perfectly as possible

They need to stay separate paths so I can save them individually

Be able to keep my dynamic black outline on the mouth

Any help would be fantastic and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a copy of layers and work on the copy.
2. Place the tounge in layer beneath the mouth.
3. Select both paths and use Pathfinder - Shape modes : Minus Front

You will get new tounge path which will perfectly alight to the mouth.

Hope this will help.